# Proof of the complement of a conditional probability

Tags: probability, proof-verification, proof-writing

I was asked to show that  $$Pr(A|B) = 1 - Pr(A|B^c)$$ but I cannot find a relation between them, I also saw that $$Pr(A|B) = 1 - Pr(A^c|B)$$ so I'm not really sure about the equation that i was asked to proof, if anyone has any advice would be great.

Comment: Suppose the probability of $A$ is $1$, regardless of $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is false.

The second expression is true.

To prove: $P(A|B) = 1-P(A^c|B)$

By definition:

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$

$1 - P(A^c|B) = 1 - \frac{P(A^cB)}{P(B)}$

So you have to prove:

$\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)} = 1 - \frac{P(A^cB)}{P(B)}$

Multiply through by $P(B)$ and get

$P(AB) = P(B) - P(A^cB)$

$P(AB) + P(A^cB) = P(B)$

Since the two terms on the LHS are mutually exclusive you can do:

$P(AB \cup A^cB) = P(B)$

And that completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to show that the top equation is false: consider the case where $A$ and $B$ are independent, whence $\mathbb P(A \mid B) = \mathbb P(A \mid B^c) = \mathbb P(A)$. If $\mathbb P(A) \neq 1/2$, you have a problem.